# How to capture character entered after key enter vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

So am trying to capture the character entered after keypressed or after the user pressed enter key.

I used this package: `npm i vue-keypress`, but i could not figure it out how to capture the characters. you can suggest any method other that this package.

```
<script>
 export default {
    components: {
        Keypress: () => import('vue-keypress')
    },
    data(){
        return {
            enteredCode:'',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        CaptureKey(){
        console.log(this.enteredCode); 
        }   
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <v-container>
        <Keypress key-event="keyup" v-model="enteredCode" :key-code="13" @success="CaptureKey()" />   
    </v-container>
</template>
```

I really don't want to use input field if possible.

thanks

Comment: The keycode 13 is for 'enter', and according to the docs for vue-keypress, you can trigger a method (@success) when 'enter' is hit with their example snippet. It doesn't detect any possible key press as you're trying to do above with v-model. So to capture 'any' key press using that plugin, you potentially would need to have seperate Keypress components listening to all of the possible keypresses, and then handling them in their own methods. I can't possibly think what you're trying to do here though, if you explain the use case it may be easier to supply a suitable answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding basically I want to scan a barcode using a regular barcode reader. thats why i want to capture the character that it reads.

Comment: Then keypresses are very likely not what you're after. The barcode reader will supply you with a string, which you should then be able to use that string in a query (presumably to your database as part of an api call to retrieve product information?).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I may not had specified my main issue here. maybe you have some links or resources regarding capturing string from a barcode scanner for vue?
thanks

Comment: FYI. The vue-keypress repository has been archived by the owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this could be used?

This listens for key events without using an input field and stores it into text data when enter has been pressed.

```html
<template>
  <div class="text">
    <label>Draft: Press enter when done.</label>
    <pre>{{ draft }}</pre>
    <label>Text:</label>
    <pre>{{ text }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      draft: "",
      text: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onKeyup(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.text = this.draft + "";
        this.draft = "";
      } else {
        this.draft += event.key;
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.onKeyup);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", this.onKeyup);
  },
};
</script>
```

Demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-text-input-without-input-field-d417j?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: thanks man appreciated